# How to use Helper to show Gravatars with Feed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null, gravatar

On the activities feed we are attempting to list out the gravatar images, but keep running into an error message.

**index.html.erb**

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
    <%= gravatar_for @user, size: 50 %>
<% end %>
```

**module UsersHelper**

```
# Returns the Gravatar for the given user.
def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 80 })

    if user.email.nil? #creates error
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest((0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join+"@mailinator.com")
    else
    gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
    end

  size = options[:size]
  gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{size}"
  image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
end
end
```

**NoMethodError in Activities#index**

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
Line: if user.email.nil?
```

If we remove `.email`, then error shows for `.name`. If we remove that too then error messages go away, but then only a default gravatar image shows instead of the user's custom image.

gravatar images show correctly when views are generated directly from the users_controller. There is the model relationship of user's `has_many :activities` and activities `belongs_to :user`.

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @activities = Activity.order("created_at desc").where(current_user.following_ids)
    end
end
```

I greatly appreciate your time & expertise!

Comment: The index is supposed to show a list of activities the logged in user is following, correct?

Comment: Thanks @papirtiger I haven't decided yet how I was going to do it, which I think aided in my confusion. For the purposes of this question Spickermann is more right, although I may use your answer in the future as a supplement or instead so thank you so much for your guidance as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to be able to call this method even if there is no user logged in (aka `user` is `nil`). You can get around this problem, by defining an anonymous user. The most simple version could look like this:

```
def gravatar_for(user, options = { size: 80 })

  unless user
    identifier = Array.new(8) { ('a'..'z').to_a.sample }.join
    user = User.new(name: 'Anonymous', email: "#{identifier}@mailinator.com")
  end

  gravatar_id  = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
  gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}?s=#{options[:size]}"
  image_tag(gravatar_url, alt: user.name, class: "gravatar")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are encountering is because you are not checking if there actually is a user to print a gravitar for.

```
undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
Line: if user.email.nil?
```

I'm guessing that this is a copy paste error and that you are looking for something like:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <%= gravatar_for activity.user, size: 50 %>
<% end %>
```

In this case you may need to add a conditional to avoid an error if there is an activity without a user:

```
<% @activities.each do |activity| %>
  <%= gravatar_for activity.user, size: 50 if activity.user %>
<% end %>
```